# Computer mouse not detecting surfaces properly

Tags: windows-10, mouse, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech mouse (don't remember the model), but I know for sure that it is an optical mouse. The buttons and scroll bar work fine, but it isn't detecting the ground/ANY surface properly. I generally use wood surfaces (which work fine with my other mouses (mice?)) and use to work perfectly with this one. After opening it up to clean the mouse buttons (they tend to get quite dusty), surface detection worked fine at first but then began to get a bit wonky (it isn't a driver issue, I've tested this on both android and windows devices). I've done the same procedure on a HP mouse without any issues as well.

For the logitech mouse, I tried to fix the optical light by cleaning it with ethanol (ensuring that the ethanol does not come in contact with the rest of the board), but that didn't work either. What could the problem be and how do I solve this?

Photos for reference:
[image: Front view of mouse]
[image: Back view of mouse]
[image: View from top side]
[image: View from bottom side]

Comment: Check the lens/prism isn't damaged or out of alignment. The focussing plane is going to be about 1mm, so any shift will stop it working.  Can't  see anything on those blurry photos.

Comment: Doesn't look damaged or misaligned, how do I gauge that?